# Store contents of string variable inside a for loop after it's execution into an array

Tags: python

I have a for loop which contains a string variable. This variable is updated every time loop is executed. So my for loop runs for 4 different times in total. I want to collect all four values of this variable and stick into an array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic pattern:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
for x in xs:
    # do something
    doubled_x = x * 2
    result.append(doubled_x)

print(result)
```